# $\sqrt[31]{12} +\sqrt[12]{31}$ is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, roots, extension-field, irrational-numbers

> Prove that $\sqrt[31]{12} +\sqrt[12]{31}$ is irrational.

I would assume that $\sqrt[31]{12} +\sqrt[12]{31}$ is rational and try to find a contradiction.

However, I don't know where to start. Can someone give me a tip on how to approach this problem?

Comment: It cant be represented in $p/q$ firm tgats all

Comment: @XPenguen I added tags for some relevant higher mathematics in order to get the question more attention. This makes it likely that 1) you will get an answer and 2) the answer you get will be one that you don't understand.  Remember that you can comment on questions to request clarification, or start a new question in order to get elaboration on an already existing answer.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890821

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ denote the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$.

The theory of [field extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) tells us that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[31]{12})$ has degree $31$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31})$ has degree $12$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and, because $(31,12)=1$, we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[31]{12})\cap\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31}) = \mathbb{Q}$.

If $\sqrt[31]{12} +\sqrt[12]{31}$ were a rational number, we would have $\sqrt[31]{12} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[31]{12})\cap\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31}) = \mathbb{Q}$.  But $\sqrt[31]{12}$ is not rational, contradiction.

Comment: What branch of mathematics is this ? I've seen this type of thing for first time.

Comment: @An_Elephant The basic ideas here would be covered in any course covering field extensions, typically an abstract algebra course.

Comment: Thanks for telling this.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simpler variant of Slade's answer:

If $\sqrt[31]{12} +\sqrt[12]{31}$ were a rational number, we would have $\sqrt[31]{12} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31})$ and so $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[31]{12}) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31})$.

But $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[31]{12})$ has dimension $31$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and so cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{31})$, which has dimension $12$.

Comment: Very slick answer. I like it.

Comment: @ASKASK, similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602764/589.

Answer (score 7):

It is known that [algebraic integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_integer) are closed under addition, subtraction, product and taking roots.

Since $12$ and $31$ are algebraic integers, so does their roots $\sqrt[31]{12}$, $\sqrt[12]{31}$. Being the sum of two such roots, $\sqrt[31]{12} + \sqrt[12]{31}$ is an algebraic integer.

It is also known that if an algebraic integer is a rational number, it will be an ordinary integer. Notice
$$2 < \sqrt[31]{12} + \sqrt[12]{31}
< \sqrt[31]{2^4} + \sqrt[12]{2^5} = 2^{\frac{4}{31}} + 2^{\frac{5}{12}} < 2\sqrt{2} < 3$$
$\sqrt[31]{12} + \sqrt[12]{31}$ isn't an integer and hence is an irrational number.

Comment: Definitely worth it to bring up this point.