# $\sqrt{98} + 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is irrational

Tags: proof-writing, radicals, irrational-numbers

Problem is to prove that $\sqrt{98} + 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is irrational.
I know that $\sqrt{98}$ and $4^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is irrational, but I don't know how to use it in this problem.

Comment: Do you know the rational root theorem? You should check out Mathologer's latest video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6AFxJdJYW4

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1595280/73324

Comment: That's an algebraic integer. An algebraic integer which is in $\Bbb Q$ must also be in $\Bbb Z$. Your calculator will tell you that's not in $\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $$7\sqrt2+\sqrt[3]4=r\in\mathbb Q.$$
Thus,
$$4=r^3-21\sqrt2r^2+294r-686\sqrt2$$ or
$$\sqrt2=\frac{r^3+294r-4}{7(3r^2+98)},$$ which is a contradiction because $\sqrt2\notin\mathbb Q$..

Comment: More generally it's true in any field where $2$ and $-6$ are not squares - see my answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

If it's rational $= a$ then cubing $\,4^{1/3} = a-7\sqrt 2\,$ yields the contradiction that $ \sqrt2$ or  $\sqrt{-6}$ is rational, by applying the theorem below with $\,b,c = -7,2\ $ (where $\sqrt d\in F$ means $\ d = f^2$ for some $\,f\in F)$

**Theorem** $ $ If $\,a,b,c\in F$ a field, 
$b\neq 0,\,$ then $\,(a+b\sqrt{c})^3\in F\,\Rightarrow\, \sqrt c\in F\,$ or $\,\sqrt{-3c}\in F$

**Proof** $\ $ Cubing    $\ (a+b\sqrt{c})^3 = b(3a^2+cb^2 ) \sqrt c + d = e\,$ for $\,d,e\in F$

When $\,3a^2+cb^2 \neq 0\,$ solving the above for $\,\sqrt c\,$ yields $\,\sqrt c \in F$.

Else  $\,\ 9a^2 = -3cb^2\,\Rightarrow\, (3a/b)^2 = -3c\,\Rightarrow\,\sqrt{-3c}\in F$.